# Який знак лапок є нормованим в українській мові?

Tags: пунктуація, типографіка

В школі нас вчили ставити лапки отак: „приклад“.

Приблизно так само виправляв лапки редактор Microsoft Word часів мого навчання в школі/інституті, замінюючи (AutoCorrect) "прямі" лапки в залежності від обраної мови тексту так:

- „українська“;
- «російська»;
- “англійська”.

Власне, саме завдяки Microsoft Word я зрозумів, що «оце» — теж є лапками (до цього я їх бачив виключно в таблицях змісту книжок російських віршів — і думав, що це якийсь специфічний знак для позначення вірша без заголовка). Хоча, навіть зрозумівши, що воно — теж лапки, я довго не міг до них звикнути, вручну виправляючи їх навіть у російських текстах.

Тим не менш, скоро я побачив:

- спочатку — що нові редактори виправляють "прямі" лапки на «отакі» навіть в українських текстах;
- потім, коли трішки розібрався — використання «отаких» лапок навіть у сучасному правописі: [§ 124. ЛАПКИ (« »)](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par124) — з використанням „отаких“ лише для другого рівня вкладеності:

  > «Ти дивився кінофільм „Данило — князь галицький“?» — спитав він товариша.

Коротше, запитання:

- Чи дійсно в 90х–2000х були зміни в нормах, що замінили „такий перший рівень (і не знаю, як раніше позначався другий, може, «отак», а може, й ніяк)“ на «такий перший рівень і „такий другий рівень“»? чи це лише розбіжність між традиціями рукописної та типографської графіки та некоректна конфігурація текстових редакторів на додачу? Шукаючи старі версії правопису на захист „звичних“ для мене лапок, я знайшов лише [проект-99](http://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/135.html), де лапки взагалі “англійські” (і ще невідомо, чи не результат це неточної оцифровки).
- Чи є якісь документи, що нормують (чи хоча б рекомендують), які саме лапки слід використовувати в українських друкованих текстах? Бо в правописі, власне, ніде не написано, що саме «такі» слід використовувати на першому рівні, а „такі“ — лише для другого. Хоча графіку самого правопису можна сприймати як зразок, але це не є конкретним правилом чи рекомендацією (і невідомо, наскільки обов'язковим для наслідування є той зразок, може, можна і так, і так).

Comment: Цікава стаття з української Вікіпедії [Лапки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лапки) включає історичний огляд їх типів та сучасне вживання в різних виданнях.

Comment: @YellowSky, це я насправді бачив. Мене цікаво: (а) Чому в 90х основними лапками вважали „такі“ (принанймні так навчали в школі і так виправляв MS Word) — а зараз «такі» (принаймні так виправляє MS Word і так у правописі)? чи ніякої зміни не було і це просто збіг — чи справді старші правописи 90х–00х містили „такі“ як основні? (б) Чи є якісь більш-менш офіційні рекомендації щодо лапок в українській типографіці (окрім тупо наслідувати графіку правопису)?

Comment: @YellowSky, до речі, їхній розділ про сучасне вживання лапок давно треба видалити, бо він не підтверджується джерелами (йдуть посилання на головні сторінки сайтів, де лапки зазвичай вперемішку, а зовсім не так, як вказано). Мабуть, сучасне використання лапок слід відслідковувати за друкованими виданнями, причому тими, які більш-менш послідовні в цьому (а у Вікіпедії я бачу лише почилання на головні сторінки Інтернет-видань, де все як попало).

Comment: Знаєте, типоґрафіка то така суб’єктивна штука... У художній книзі перший рядок абзацу може бути відсунуто не направо від лівого поля абзацу, а вліво, тобто він може виступати вліво від лівого краю вирівнювання,  лапки можуть позначати чим завгодно, хоч •...•, хоч <...>, тощо. Але коли мова йде про строго наукове видання, чи то літературне, чи то наукове дослідження, то тут від чинного правопису годі й ухилятися, треба йому слідувати. Новини ж, а особливо публіцистика застосовують або корпоративну, або авторську пунктуацію, для них ніщо не указ...

Comment: Перепрошую, невдала спроба додати до старого коменту: «(Це я про сучасність. Зі старими в них все ок — але мене цікавлять 90і–00і.)» @YellowSky, так а в правописі ж чітко не сказано, як саме треба (в плані самої графіки). Там лише приклади, які можна трактувати по-різному. І знов таки, навіть в правописі — чи були змінені ці приклади в 90х–00х?

Comment: Питання дуже цікаве, проте, орієнтуватися саме на продукти Microsoft напевно не варто, бо в українській розкладці клавіатури, наприклад, апостроф з'явився не так давно. Щодо того як в школі вчать писати лапки "від руки" і як вони використовуються в книжках - це також дві різні традиції, порівняйте хоча б як пишеться буква "л" у типографіці і від руки (Л і /\ ).

Comment: @Artemix, 1926, 1928, 1929, 1933, 1938, 1940, 1943 — „“, 1946 (I), 1960 (II), 1990 (III) — ?, 1993 (IV) — «», 1996 (V), 1997 (VI), 1998 (VII), 1999, 2000, 2002 — ?, 2003 — «», 2004, 2005 — ?, 2007 — «», 2008, 2010 — ?, 2012, 2015 — «» (я можу припустити, що після 1993 лапки не змінювалися, але II і III видання важливі, бо саме лапки 1980-х – початку 1990-х могли попасти в MS і в око школяра 1990-х).

Comment: Цікаво що на самому постері "Галицький" написано з великої букви, а у правописі - з маленької. https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: @Artemix, мабуть, тому що «Данило Галицький» — це ім'я, і вони вирішили увіпхнути «— князь» всередину. Мабуть, найправильніше все ж «Данило [Галицький] — це князь [галицький]», ІМХО. Ви це спеціально сюди написали, щоби до мене звернутися (бо лапок, здається, це не стосується) — чи помилилися textbox'ом?

Comment: Це до цитати коментар: "«Ти дивився кінофільм „Данило — князь галицький“?» — спитав він товариша."

Comment: @Artemix,⁠ ааа…

Comment: @Artemix, ну бо за правилами має бути з маленької, але на постері вирішили стилізувати :). В яких випадках треба зберігати не зовсім правильне написання оригіналу при цитуванні, а в яких ні — окрема тема :).

Comment: @Artemix, по-перше, у Вікіпедії могли не приділити увагу цьому (чи не знати). По-друге, в загальному випадку, я думаю, не зовсім вірне написання оригіналу при цитуванні можна і виправляти, і залишати як є — в залежності від мети. Так от в правописі: (а) не хочуть популяризувати не найправильніше написання, бо кожне слово може сприйматися як еталон; (б) передається насправді усний діалог («спитав він товариша»), де зберігати орфографічні помилки чи стилізацію немає ніякого мотиву. А у Вікіпедії звикли до [}{0ТТ@бь)Чів](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хоттабич_(фільм)) і слідувати оригіналу.

Answer (score 6):

Щодо українських документів та рекомендацій, є посібник Партико 3. В.
[Загальне редагування: нормативні основи](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Partyko_Zinovii/Zahalne_redahuvannia_normatyvni_osnovy.djvu). (Навчальний посібник. — Л.: ВФ Афіша, 2006., с. 277)

Ось, що в ньому сказано:

> Цитати можна виділяти трьома способами:
>
> 1. а) за допомогою лапок; при цьому,  коли всередині цитати є інші    лапки, їх подають у такій послідовності: ***«хххх "ххххх " хххх»***;
> 2. б) за допомогою шрифтових виділень; в) за допомогою поліграфічних 
>      засобів, наприклад, лівосторонніх втягувань, міжабзацних відступів
>      зверху та  знизу цитати тощо.

Питання зовнішнього вигляду лапок взагалі не тема правопису, за традицією це царина технічних редакторів, в СРСР традиційно було два типу лапок: *«типографські»* та *„рукописні“*. Звичайно, що пересічні громадяни в докомп'ютерну епоху не мали відношення до видавничої справи, тому ніхто ніколи не робив акцентів на зовнішньому вигляді лапок, у ГОСТах (наприклад ГОСТ 7.1—84), що нормують видавничу діяльність детально описувалось, де лапки вживати, але сам вигляд лапок не описувався.

З появою комп'ютерів друкувати літературу стало дуже легко, це почали робити люди без фахової підготовки, часто покладаючись на систему виправлення MS Ворду, але вона не була налаштована згідно наших нормативів, тому ми сьогодні спостерігаємо деякий безлад у цьому питанні.

Comment: Перепрошую, а яким чином іншомовна граматика (друга половина відповіді) нормує українську мову? Так само, як і ГОСТ 7.1—84, який щось регулює «*на русском и других языках.*»

Comment: @bytebuster , Щодо традицій, це радянський ГОСТ (ГОСТ 7.1—84 — система стандартів по видавничій та бібліотечній справі), введений у 1986, він не стосується граматики чи правопису, тому говорити, що це російські норми і вони не мають відношення до української мови, мабуть, неправильно. Ці ГОСТИ нормували всю видавничу діяльність в СРСР

Answer (score 0):

[Ось цікавий допис](https://golovonog.org/pro-lapky/) на тему:

> В українській мові є два нормативні варіанти лапок — «*лапки-ялинка*» та
>   „*німецькі лапки*“. Використовуються задля вирізнення прямої мови,
>   цитат, заголовків, а також слів, ужитих у непрямому, найчастіше
>   іронічному значенні. Наступного разу, коли побачите “текст” або
>   ‘текст’, виправіть маркером.

Також цікава довідка:

[image]

Comment: А де у тому бложику написано, що це — нормована форма? Допис у блозі свідчить лише про власну думку автора. У тексті запитання ОП запитує про зміни у 1990-2000 рр і про те, чи є якісь документи, що нормують…

Comment: Блоґ непоганий, за що дякую. Але, дійсно, не розкриває чи не підтверджує нормованість.