# Цитування іншомовного тексту

Tags: типографіка, синтаксис

Як відомо, формат цитат в тексті в українській і англійській різняться не лише формою лапок; себто, коли ми цитуємо український текст, то крапка виноситься за лапки, як-от:

> Це текст, «а це цитата».

в той час, коли англійською писатимемо так:

> This is a text, and “this is a quote.”

ба навіть кому слід ставити перед закриваючими лапками:

> “This is a quote,” and this is a text.

В тонкощі форматування цитат на інших мовах не вникатиму, але суть питання та ж: а що як ми в українському тексті даємо англійську або іншу іншомовну цитату в оригіналі: чи слід користуватися українським форматуванням, а чи оригінальним? Якщо слід переробляти на український лад, накшталт:

> «This is a quote», як той к'зав

то що робити з цитуванням блоками, де можуть траплятися свої унутрішні цитати? Теж переробляти, чи залишати в оригіналі? Існують якісь офіційні ґайдлайни на це?

Comment: Залежить від типу видання. Бо у підручнику англійської мови природно давати фрагменти тексту, цитати, або учбові тексти форматовані за англійськими правилами, бо люди вивчають мову (і культуру) і готові до такої зустрічі. Щодо художніх текстів українською, то тут, як на мене, перенесення іншомовних правил недоречне. Наприклад у німецьких текстах лапки використовуються »в інший бік«, і пересічному читачеві буде не зрозуміло, чому у частини цитат лапки «правильні», а у іншої »переплутані«.

Comment: Лапки у різних мовах: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8 (корисно щоб уявити що може бути, зверніть увагу на фінську мову).

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/568/

Answer (score 6):

Цей офіційний *посібник* зазвичай називається *український правопис* й зазначає, що слід користуватися українською пунктуацією

> <sup>Український правопис. — К.: Наукова думка, 2015. — 288 с.
>
>   └ [§ 124. Лапки (« »)](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par124)</sup>
>   У лапки беруться:
>
> 1. Цитати, причому й тоді, коли цитата входить у середину речення як його складова частина:
>
> ...*Усім нам, працівникам галузі перекладу, цього «високого мистецтва», за виразом К. І. Чуковського, або «благородного ремесла», як говорить Марія Домбровська, корисно пам’ятати слова О. Твардовського про С. Маршака як перекладача Бернса: «Він зробив його росіянином, залишивши шотландцем». Я б додав ще: «Він зробив його Маршаком, залишивши Бернсом», — бо ж не сама тільки печать національності, а й печать індивідуальності лежить на кожному талановитому перекладі* [(Рильський)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).
>
> **Примітка 3.** а) Кома, крапка з комою, двокрапка й тире ніколи не ставляться перед закритими лапками, а тільки після них.
>   б) Знак питання, знак оклику й крапки ставляться або перед закритими лапками, якщо вони відносяться лише до слів, поставлених у лапках, або після лапок, якщо ці розділові знаки стосуються всього речення.
>
> **Примітка 4.** Якщо знак питання, знак оклику й крапки стоять перед закритими лапками, то після лапок ті самі знаки не повторюються; неоднакові ж знаки можуть, залежно від змісту, ставитися одночасно й перед закритими лапками, й після них:
>   *Чи знайомі ви з романом Герцена «Хто винен?»*
>   Але: *Невже ти не чув, як кликали: «До зброї, товариші!»?*

Щодо самої [цитати](http://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/sintaksis_i_punktuacija/citati/7-1-0-235)

> У цитаті не можна нічого змінювати, навіть розділових знаків.

Comment: не можу знайти де у цитаті написано, що для іншомовного тексту слід користуватись українською пунктуацією

Comment: Зрозуміло, тобто написане дійсне для цитат будь-якою мовою. Дякую.

Comment: Щодо першої частини — згоден (справді, в українському тексті має бути українська пунктуація і типографіка — в правописі нічого не сказано про те, що іншомовні цитати наводяться якось по-іншому (окрім, хіба що, особливих випадків, на зразок наведеного Artemix'ом [прикладу про підручник іноземної мови](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2574#comment4228_2574))).

Comment: А от щодо «у цитаті не можна нічого змінювати, навіть розділових знаків» — по-моєму, Ви неправильне це сприйняли (чи принаймні навели так, що в читача може створитися неправильна інтерпретація). По-перше, ця фраза просто не відповідає дійсності — є різні способи цитування; наприклад, якщо в оригіналі помилка або малозрозумілі моменти, цитувальник може виправити/пояснити їх з використанням квадратних дужок («з криком і лайкою хапали [безпритульні] в кухаря судки з котлетами») — а може залишити все як є, сказавши щось типу «орфографія оригіналу збережена» або [sic](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic).

Comment: @Sasha, Follower - уникайте дискусій у коментарях. Дякую. Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63331/discussion-on-answer-by-follower---).

Comment: У довіднику Мільчина (1972 р.) описано що можна змінювати в цитатах, багато цікавих прикладів (наприклад виправлення дореформеної орфографії): http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000026/st055.shtml Нажаль про іноземні фрагменти в цьому виданні не написано (з тих пір вже вийшло декілька видань).